# Not able to run python from command prompt using 'python' command; it only takes 'py -3'

Tags: python

I have installed Python 3.8.2 in my Windows 10 laptop

When I run the command 'python' in the command prompt, it gives me a blank response and goes back to the command prompt.

However when I run the command 'py -3' in the command prompt, python is launched.

What can be the reason for this. Is there anyway I can launch python using the 'python' command in cmd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why does it need to be python? py is basically the same thing. Looks like you didn't check ambient variable in python installation. Just add python folder in PATH ambient variable  and you're ready to go